# select the grandparent list of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight the particular anchor tags' grandparent list(`<li>`).I am using `window.location.href` to select particular anchor tag. But i don't know how to highlight that particular anchor tags' grandparent `li`?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item">

    <li><a></a></li>
    <li>/*want to highlight this*/
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="something"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery("#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul li ul li a").each(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == window.location.href){          
        jQuery(this).css("background-Color", "#FEDFB5");
        jQuery(this).parents("ul").find('#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul li a').css( "background-color", "red" );
    }

 });
```

the above code affects all anchor tags in ul? need help

Comment: child  `<ui><li>` element placement is looking wrong.. it should inside just parent `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1r7ybwk/1/

first change your html to:

```
<ul id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item">
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li class="level-1"><span>/*want to highlight this*/</span>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="something">asdf</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

then add this in your css:

```
li.highlight span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

and your javascript to:

```
jQuery("#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item li ul li a").each(function () {
  if (jQuery(this).attr('href') == 'something') { // for debugging window.location.href){          
    jQuery(this).css("background-Color", "#FEDFB5");
    jQuery(this).closest('li[class^="level-1"]').addClass('highlight');
  }
});
```

works as wanted.

alternatively you could use the parents function:

```
jQuery(this).parents('li[class^="level-1"]').addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: closest highlights the same li, it is not hightlight that parent. because i am selecting anchor tag, that's parent is list?

Comment: no it does not work, we can get same item by closest, can i get the parent of that same item ?

Comment: parentsUntil changes whole container's background? any other way?

Comment: it changes whole websites background, yeah i placed class level-1 too? closest method comes nearly, can u say the same way?

Comment: i tried this jQuery(this).closest('ul').closest('ul li').css( "background-color", "pink" ); as said by Yunus, nothing changed, is there any mistake?

Comment: no change, i don't know what's wrong. jQuery(this).closest("li").css('background-color', 'red'); this only gives result. but same item?

Comment: did you check the fiddle i linked?

Comment: yes in that fiddle you are using <span>want to highlight this</span>. But if you change it to anchor tag, does not work?

Comment: If you change the span to an a, you have to update the css as well ;) http://jsfiddle.net/m1r7ybwk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you have used wrong selector `ul#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item` because `ul` have `id` so use without space and element first and `parents()` target to all so insteand of `parents()` use `parent()` function

```
jQuery("ul#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item > li > ul > li a").each(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == window.location.href){          
        jQuery(this).css("background-Color", "#FEDFB5");
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().css( "background-color", "pink" );
    }

 });
```

[**DEMO LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/1upwavug/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cpn9r6g1/1/)

```
$("#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "something"){
       $(this).closest("ul").closest("li").css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
});
```